# Debugger doesn't break on a simple aws iot core application

Tags: pycharm, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to debug with PyCharm a very simple AWS IOT Core application.
This is the pubsub.py from the AWS tutorial.
The application is cloned from here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2.git, in this location: /sample/pubsub.py.

At some point, there is a call to `mqtt_connection.subscribe(...,callback=on_message_received)`

It is working fine, and the code within `on_message_received` is running (The prints command actually print). However, putting a breakpoint - the PyCharm debugger doesn't stop there.

A related question: On what thread the callback is being called, or is it asyncio thing (I don't see any sign to async io).